# rails associations - How would you represent this relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am trying to figure out a best way to represent the following relationship.

```
Newspaper has_many Articles
Newspaper has_many Subscribers
```

Subscribers are allowed to save the articles for their personal page.

Two Questions:

1) How would the relationship look like in rails? How would the action 'save' look like?

The following using has_many does not seem right to me:

```
class ArticleController < ApplicationController
  def save
    a = Article.find(101)
    @user.saved_articles << a
  end
end
```

2) Do I need a join table Saved_Articles that looked like this?

```
Saved_Articles
----------------
user_id, article_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is a many-to-many relationship. In terms of Rails associations, this is one way of defining it:

```
class Newspaper
  has_many :articles
  has_many :subscribers
end

class Subscriber
  belongs_to :newspaper
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end

class Article
  belongs_to :newspaper
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribers
end
```

By using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you will need a join table, but it would need to be called `articles_subscribers` and would have `subscriber_id` and `article_id` fields:

```
articles_subscribers
--------------------
article_id
subscriber_id
```

Your `save` action would then look something like the following, assuming `@user` was an instance of `Subscriber`:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def save
    @user.articles << Article.find(params[:id])

    # handle the response - render or redirect
  end
end
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many for more information on `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer QUestion #1**:

in models/newspaper.rb:
has_many :articles
has_many :subscribers

in controllers/newspapers_controller.rb

```
def create
  @newspaper = NewsPaper.new(params[:newspaper])
  if @newspaper.save
    redirect_to 
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for Question #2**:
You don't need a join table for this. Just 3 separate tables (newspapers, articles, and subscribers) would be fine. The foreign keys for newspaper_id would be in articles and subscribers.